# SharePoint 2013 URL help

Tags: publishing-site, publishing

I was updating our SP site and there was a glitch with power.
Now when I try opening the site it gives me `Page Not Found` error.

I can view it in Call Tree and SharePoint Designer 2013 but not in the browser. 
I feel that the problem is the URL has been changed, but can't figure out how to change it back without opening it.

Comment: Someone please help

Answer (score 1):

If the Welcome Page is not found, then from open it with SharePoint Designer, right-click on a working page and click "Set as Homepage".

You can also navigate to Navigate to `http://sharepointsite**/_layouts/settings.aspx` and update the Welcome Page from the Look and Feel: Title and Welcome Page Menu.

If its the MasterPage that is corrupt/not found, you can also navigate to the MasterPage in SharePoint Designer, (`/_catalogs/masterpage/`) select a working MasterPage, like seattle.master. Right-Click on it and then click set as default master page / set as default custom master page.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  The _layouts option brought back the same error - page not found.

Comment: I'm unable to open the subsite or any pages of the site in designer.  The .aspx file url is incorrect on the home page.  I tried creating a new page or list page within same subsite to no avail.  So frustrated.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What is available when you open it in SharePoint Designer?